# java jtextpane set gap or setleading or setlinespacing

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

thanks for the help that you can lend me, I have some time looking for the solution for the spacing between lines of paragraphed in a jtextpane and I applied several suggestions without success to modify the spacing between lines, then I indicate the code that I have made for your opinions . Thank you

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class jtextpane7 extends JTextPane {

    public jtextpane7() {
        super();
        super.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        super.setMargin(new Insets(10, 5, 10, 5)); //top, left, bottom, right

    }
   // @Override
   //    public FontMetrics getFontMetrics(Font font) {
   ////        FontMetrics f = super.getFontMetrics(font);
   ////        return new FontMetricsWrapper(f) {
   ////            @Override
   ////            public int getHeight() {
   ////                return 10;  // Gives line height in pixels
   ////            }
   ////        };

    @Override
    public void setText(String t) {
        super.setText(setStyle(t)); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private String setStyle(String t) {
        return "<div align='justify' width='50px' height='120px' style='font-family:Arial;  font-size:14px; line-height:150%;'>" + t + "</div>";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        jtextpane7 editor = new jtextpane7();
        editor.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        editor.setContentType("text/html");
        editor.setText(" <html>\n"
                + "  <head>\n"
                + "    \n"
                + "  </head>\n"
                + "  <body>\n"
                + "    <div align=\"justify\" width=\"50px\" height=\"120px\" style=\"line-height: 15px\">\n"
                + "      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, e del a&#241;o 2017 prueba de linea ancho\n"
                + "    </div>\n"
                + "  </body>\n"
                + "</html>   ");
    editor.selectAll();
    MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet(editor.getParagraphAttributes());
    StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, 55.0f);//55.0f value test failed
    editor.setCaretPosition(0);
    editor.setParagraphAttributes(set, false);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(editor);

    }
}

class FontMetricsWrapper extends FontMetrics {

    private final FontMetrics target;

    public FontMetricsWrapper(FontMetrics target) {
        super(target.getFont());
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public int bytesWidth(byte[] data, int off, int len) {
        return target.bytesWidth(data, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public int charWidth(char ch) {
        return target.charWidth(ch);
    }

    @Override
    public int charWidth(int codePoint) {
        return target.charWidth(codePoint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return super.getLeading() + super.getAscent() + super.getDescent() + 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try editor.setParagraphAttributes(set, true); ?

Comment: yes, i tried and nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use HTML. Instead use normal text and add attributes with the text.

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextPaneAttributes extends JPanel
{

    public TextPaneAttributes()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight" );

//      DefaultHighlighter highlighter =  (DefaultHighlighter)textPane.getHighlighter();
//      highlighter.setDrawsLayeredHighlights(false);

        //  Define some character and paragraph attributes

        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

        SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

        SimpleAttributeSet left = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(left, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);

        //  Change attributes on some existing text

        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 3, keyWord, false);
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(8, 5, green, true);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(20, 1 , center, false);

        //  Add some text with attributes

        try
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nNormal text", null);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nGreen text centered", green);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1 , center, false);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nKeyword text", keyWord);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1 , left, false);

            //  Newly typed text at the end of the document will inherit the
            //  "keyword" attributes unless we remove the attributes

            textPane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
            textPane.getInputAttributes().removeAttributes(keyWord);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}

        //  Add text pane to frame

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 250 ) );
        add( scrollPane );

        //  Create a Button panel

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //  Add a Bold button

        JButton bold = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() );
        buttons.add( bold );

        //  Add Right Alignment button

        JButton right = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.AlignmentAction("Align Right", StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT) );
        buttons.add( right );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextPaneAttributes());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

There are also attributes you can use to set the line spacing.

Comment: @NelsonEduardo as stated above by camickr don't post an answer on your own... (Which is a copy of his answer) and instead accept his!